# c++ How to assign a member function of a class to a function pointer and call

Tags: c++, function-pointers

```
//The code example is as follows

//Defines a generic class pointer and function pointer
template<class T>
T* A;
template<class T>
void(T::*test)(int);



//assign in the function
template<class T>
void set(T* obj,void(T::*func)(int)){
    A=obj;
    test=func;
}


//Called here from other libraries, don’t care about the specific implementation class
//void call(int i){
// (A->*test)(i);
//}


//The class B here may be any class that needs to be registered, such as class C, class D...
class B{
    public:
        void func1(int idx);
};
void B::func1(int idx){
    cout << idx << endl;
}


void bindA(){
    B b;
    void (B::*func)(int);
    func=&B::func1;
    B *n=&b;
    set(n,func);
}

void main(){
    bindA();
}
```

The problem I encountered is that the compilation will report an error prompt：missing template arguments before '=' token
The error location is in the

```
A=obj;    
test=func;
```

line of the

```
void set(T* obj,void(T::*func)(int))
```

function.

How can I bind the 'A' and 'test' to the object and member function specified by the set function, so that it can be called by the call function?

Comment: Please don't use `c` tag for c++ questions. They are very different languages.

Comment: The description of the tags also say so explicitly. Please read them!  As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please don't spam with unrelated tags. C and C++ are two *very* different languages, so tag only the one language you're actually programming in.

Comment: Concerning your question, there is a `T` which is sometimes used as a type and sometimes as a template parameter, which makes this really unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.

1. The `set` function is missing a template list declaration.
2. `A` is not a pointer. Its a template. Use `A<T>` if you want to use it as a pointer. Same  with `test`.
3. Use `func=&B::func1;` instead of `func=&b::func1;`

Comment: Yes, I’m sorry, the sample code is simplified based on the problem I encountered, I haven’t checked and modified it yet

Answer (score 0):

I made some minor changes:move global variable(A test set) to a template class(Binder). Here:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
//The code example is as follows

//Defines a generic class pointer and function pointer
template<class T>
class Binder {
public:
    T* A;
    void(T::*test)(int);
    void set(T* obj, void(T::*func)(int)) {
        A = obj;
        test = func;
    }
};

//The class B here may be any class that needs to be registered, such as class C, class D...
class B {
public:
    void func1(int idx);
};
void B::func1(int idx) {
    cout << idx << endl;
}


void bindA() {
    B b;
    void (B::*func)(int);
    func = &B::func1;
    B *n = &b;
    Binder<B> binderB;
    binderB.set(n, func);
}

void main() {
    bindA();
}
```

Comment: The template here is packaged, and I can only call a global function or a function of a global object where I need to call, which is the  'call' function in my example.
And this global object or function pointer can only be assigned in my initialization function 'bindA()',
So even if the template class is changed to
`......


template<class T>
Binder<T> &callBinder;

void bindA() {
    B b;
    void (B::*func)(int);
    func = &B::func1;
    B *n = &b;
    Binder<B> binderB;
    binderB.set(n, func);
    callBinder=binderB; 
}
`
when initializing the global object,

Comment: my compiler will still prompt: missing template arguments before '=' token
The same problem as I posted for help.

Answer (score 0):

two points
1.to define a pointer to T

```
// alias template  
 template<class T>  
using ptr = T*;      
// the name 'ptr<T>' is now an alias for pointer to T
```

2.use the `std::funtion()`to wrap the class member funtion,because there is a `this` pointer as a argument

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed an explicit code illustrating point 2.

Comment: i am sorry, I don't know the details